# Quit cmd while exe is running

Tags: cx-freeze

I have a .exe (PyQt5 + python3), the issue is that when I start the application, the cmd window is always initialized in the background.
I want that the cmd window is not initialized.

This is the code that I used to convert to .exe:

```
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import *

setup(
    name = "interfaz",
    options = {'build_exe': {'packages': ['cv2', 'numpy']}},
    executables=[
        Executable(
            "interfaz.py",
        )
    ]
)
```

This is an image showing the app:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the `cx_Freeze` [documentation](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#windows-command-prompt-appears-briefly), in order to avoid that the command prompt appears briefly under Windows, you need to:

> Freeze your application with the `Win32GUI` base [...]. This doesn’t use a console window, and reports errors in a dialog box.

Try thus to modify your setup script as follows:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name="interfaz",
      options={'build_exe': {'packages': ['cv2', 'numpy']}},
      executables=[Executable("interfaz.py", base=base)])
```